# MySQL: does "NOT IN()" function not allow 'NULL' values in the results set?

Tags: mysql, notnull

I have a simple table on my local server.

```
mysql> desc table ;
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| count | int(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec
```

It has just three records in it.

```
mysql> select * from uday ;
+------+-------+
| id   | count |
+------+-------+
|    1 |     1 | 
|    2 |     2 | 
|    3 |     0 | 
|    4 |  NULL | 
+------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now, why is that i am not seeing the fourth column in the below result..?

```
mysql> select * from uday where count NOT IN (0) ;
mysql> select * from uday where count != 0 ;
+------+-------+
| id   | count |
+------+-------+
|    1 |     1 | 
|    2 |     2 | 
+------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

how about the 4th record...? Its not visible in the result.
NULL is not 0 RIGHT...?

please ignore if it looks pretty foolish as I am not even competitive in coding part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
col1 not in (1,2,null)
```

is shorthand for:

```
col1 <> 1 and col1 <> 2 and col1 <> null
```

In SQL's [three-valued logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic), `col1 <> null` returns `unknown`.  And `true and true and unknown` also returns `unknown`.  Since `where` only accepts `true`, and not `unknown`, the row with `null` is filtered out of the result set.